# Distinct value in two column

Tags: mysql

I have a query in mysql

```
select f1,f2,f3 from tableName;
```

I want to remove duplicate value in field f1 and f2 only,

I have tired as follows

```
select f1,f2,f3 from tableName
group by f1,f2;
```

But it will remove duplicates in f1 only.Any body can suggest me that how to remove duplicates in f1 and f2.

```
topic_id    topic_name                    question_type
2237    Understanding Diversity           Comprehensive
2237    Understanding Diversity           Easy
2237    Understanding Diversity           Application
44315   Bhasha, boli, lipi, or Vayakaran  Intermediate
```

above is sample output having distinct value in question_type column only
here i want to remove duplicates from question_type and topic_id

expected output: having both topic_id and question_type distinct values

```
 44315  Bhasha, boli, lipi, or Vayakaran  Intermediate
 2237   Understanding Diversity           Comprehensive
```

Comment: Give sample data and expected result. For now your question is not completely clear

Comment: And what is the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My SQL really isn't that great, but I think you need to do what is called a nested SELECT statement.

Here is the manual reference.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

That would make the SQL look something like this.

```
SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM (SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM tableName AS table1 GROUP BY f1) AS table2 GROUP BY f2;
```

Note, that I had to use the AS to create an alias, else "tableName" would conflict with the parent SQL select.

Comment: "My SQL really isn't that great" --- actually it is great. Any "mature" DBMS wouldn't even run your *incorrect* query. So it is great at least because it allows to run the queries that make no sense

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the SQL I posted. So please explain what the "incorrect" part is, rather then just voting down an answer that was based upon this query, which executed just fine in MySQL Workbench. SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM receipts AS table1 GROUP BY smart_category_id) AS table2 GROUP BY smart_vendor_id;

Comment: 1) I didn't downvote 2) all "mature" DBMS wouldn't allow you to select anything that is not used in `GROUP BY` or isn't used in aggregation functions (this is the expected behaviour described in ANSI SQL). In your case - when you `group by f1` - which `f2` and `f2` are supposed to be returned? Mysql allows doing so, but it still makes no sense

Comment: ah yes, my bad. I see what you are saying. The outer select is going to group by F2 no matter what the inner select provides. Would it work if the outer select GROUP BY F1, F2?

Comment: it "would work" in mysql in any way, but it still would return unpredictable values for the columns that haven't been used in `group by` clause or aggregate functions

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there - you need to group the last column also. I can just guess the usage, so I added a sorted summary of covered `question_type`s that might be handy for search or output:

```
SELECT
  topic_id,
  topic_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT question_type ORDER BY question_type) AS question_types
FROM tableName
GROUP BY topic_id, topic_name;
```

Output is:

```
'2237', 'Understanding Diversity', 'Application,Comprehensive,Easy'
'44315', 'Bhasha, boli, lipi, or Vayakaran', 'Itermediate'
```

Comment: This query was run exactly as it is here on the MySQL console. You may have a different problem - can you post the error message?